# Visual Studio Debugger silently continues when stepping over a specific line of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, winapi, com

I'm using the windows API to get a handle to a `IAudioEndpointVolume` and register a `IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback`. I've also got a `IMMDeviceEnumerator` with a registered callback for `IMMNotificationClient` so that when the default device changes I release the `IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback` and `IAudioEndpointVolume` and store new ones.

However, my program seems to silently crash on the callback thread when releasing `IAudioEndpointVolume` with no exception or output that I can see. Even when breaking on the line and trying to step over it will silently continue without getting to the next statement but also without the debugger coming down.

```
if(_volumeEndPoint)
{
    if(_callback)
    {
        HRESULT hrUnReg = _volumeEndPoint->UnregisterControlChangeNotify(this);
        if(hrUnReg != S_OK)
        {
            std::cout << hrUnReg; // this reports successful
        }
    }

    _volumeEndPoint->Release(); // <--- cannot step over this line
    _volumeEndPoint = nullptr;
}

if(deviceEndPoint == nullptr)
{
    return;
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Enabling all the exceptions in Debug->Windows->Exception Settings
- Adding a try/catch all exceptions

Feels like it's probably related to it being a callback on a different thread? I'm not that well versed in C++ nor the WinAPI and the COM stuff so almost certain I'm doing something stupid but it would be good if it could tell me an error of some kind.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nn-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolumecallback) specifically warns about deadlock.  The presence of the `_callback` variable in the snippet suggests that's what you see.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that in the documentation:

- The client should never call the IAudioEndpointVolume::UnregisterControlChangeNotify method during an event callback.
- The client should never release the final reference on an EndpointVolume API object during an event callback.

Comment: I should clarify the callback is from `IMMNotificationClient::OnDefaultDeviceChanged`, not from `IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback::OnNotify`. Would that still fall under those deadlock instructions in the documentation?

Comment: It doesn't, but if it quacks like a duck then it probably is a duck.  WASAPI is prone to such deadlock, protecting itself against callbacks doing anything that changes internal state in a way that destabilizes the api.  Delaying the call is the workaround, usually done with PostMessage().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the program wasn't silently crash, it is deadlock! You can check the stack trace when the program silently crash, maybe the stack trace like this:

[silently crash stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKkKg.png)

MSDN doesn't write anything about it and how to avoid this situation, I tried many times and many way to deal with this problem, but I failed.

However, I found two rules you need to follow, this rules only work for the situation that you call `RegisterControlChangeNotify` ：

1. Any devices in system that can only be manager by ONE `IMMDevice`, you can't create multiple `IMMDevice` instance to manager the device.
2. In `IMMNotificationClient` callback, you can't release `IMMDevice`. You can release the instance on the other thread.